# Let $h$ be a homomorphism from A onto B, $g$ a homomorphism from A onto C such that $ \ker g\subset \ker h$. Prove there's a homo. $f$ from B onto C

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I know that

$A/\operatorname{ker}h \cong B$

$A/\operatorname{ker}g \cong B$

I've never done these and my professor has never mentioned them until now so if anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: (i) Are $A,B$ and $C$ groups? I suppose the solution is essentially the same if you are working with rings/vector spaces/modules/whatever, but you should specify what $A,B$ and $C$ are. (ii) Please put the question in the body of the post instead of the title.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $f: C \to B$ by $g(a) \mapsto h(a)$. Then, you can show $f$ is well defined, and a surjective homomorphism.